# HAProxy Passthrough SSL where the target is the caller host

Tags: proxy, haproxy

I would like to configure HAProxy for VPC Transitive peering issue, so HAProxy should only forward requests further to the host which caller want to reach.

My configuration looks like:

```html
# Global settings
global
    log 127.0.0.1:514  local0
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon
# Default SSL material locations
#ssl-default-bind-ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM
#ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

# Default backend configuration
defaults
    log global
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    option dontlognull
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client 50000
    timeout server 50000

frontend https_forwarder
    bind :8888
    mode tcp 
    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s

    #acl is_gke_ssl req.ssl_hello_type 1

    #use_backend tcp_backend if is_gke_ssl
    default_backend tcp_backend

backend tcp_backend
    mode tcp

# Define a listen block to enable statistics and monitoring (optional)
listen stats
    bind :9000  # Any port for stats monitoring
    mode tcp
    stats enable
    stats uri /haproxy_stats  # Access HAProxy stats at http://haproxy-ip:9000/haproxy_stats
    stats realm HAProxy\ Statistics
    stats auth haproxy:haproxy  # Replace with your desired username and password
```

When I'm calling any endpoint through the proxy, like this:

```
curl -x "http://10.223.113.221:8888" "https://www.google.com"
```

I'm receiving the response:

```
curl: (56) Proxy CONNECT aborted
```

How to configure HAproxy properly for my use case?